# How to run github django projects on pc after cloning

Tags: django

This type of error is occurring in my system:

[image]

Comment: You have to run `python manage.py runserver` from **ecommerce-master** directory and  you try to run from ecommerce.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in the same directory as the manage.py file. You are trying to run the command inside

`D:\ecommerce-master\ecommerce`

when you need to be inside

`D:\ecommerce-master`